# Laravel: How to update the MySQL by Eloquent in child process?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I write a Laravel Command, and it will fork some child process. Child process will update the DB by Eloquent.

Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Console\BaseCommand;
use App\Item;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Test extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'test';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Item::first();
        $children = [];
        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $pid = pcntl_fork();
            if ($pid == -1) {
                die('pmap fork error');
            } else {
                if ($pid) {
                    $children[] = $pid;
                } else {
                    Item::first(); exit;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            pcntl_waitpid($child, $status);
        }
    }
}
```

Run my code:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/ECAME$ php artisan test


  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 116. Packet size=6255201 (SQL: select * from `items` where `items`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)



  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 100. Packet size=6238815 (SQL: select * from `items` where `items`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)



  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 0. Packet size=2816 (SQL: select * from `items` where `items`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)



  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 116. Packet size=6381412 (SQL: select * from `items` where `items`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)



  [ErrorException]
  Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 100. Packet size=6238815



  [ErrorException]
  Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 116. Packet size=6381412



  [ErrorException]
  Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 116. Packet size=6255201



  [ErrorException]
  Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 0. Packet size=2816
```

What's the reason behind that? And How to update the MySQL by Eloquent in child process?

PS:

I think the reason for that problem is, all child processes use the same MySQL connection which forked from the parent process.

If I don't call `Item::first()` in the parent process before call `fork()`, it works well. (In my real use case, I can't do that... The parent process will do a lot with MySQL before fork child process.)

Because in that case, the MySQL connection doesn't initialize in the parent process, so every child process will initialize a connection on their own.

So, if it's the case, how to initialize a new MySQL connection for each child process after forked?

Comment: this link may help you https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/packets-out-of-order-error?page=1

Comment: Forked processes can't share (global) resources. The real question is - why are you forking and is that the real solution to your problem? You have to establish MySQL connection in every forked request.

Comment: Hi! I agree with previous comment... I don't want to critic your approach with forking process, but is this really only one solution and is it really nessesary?... I am curious - what are reasons, that pushed you to choose this solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Since it's all about the connection dying, you can solve this by simply reconnecting to the database.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

[...]

public function handle()
{
    User::first();

    $children = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
    {
        $pid = pcntl_fork();

        if ($pid == -1) 
        {
            die('pmap fork error');
        } 
        else 
        {
            if ($pid) 
            {
                $children[] = $pid;
            } 
            else
            {
                DB::connection()->reconnect(); // <----- add this
                User::first(); exit;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($children as $child) 
    {
        pcntl_waitpid($child, $status);
    }
}
```

I tested this in Laravel 5.6 and it works.

Comment: Show us some more appropriate code to reproduce the bug then.

Answer (score 0):

And if you define a second ddbb with equal parameters in your database.php , and you launch your Item::first based in the second connection ?

```
# Primary database connection
            'mysql' => [
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => 'localhost',
                'database'  => 'myddbb',
                'username'  => 'root',
                'password'  => '',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            ],
  # Secondary database connection
        'mysql_forConnectChildren' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'myddbb',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ],
```

Later

```
 $item = \DB::connection('mysql_forConnectChildren')->select('select * from Item')->get(1);
```

I not tested but i think can works

Answer (score 0):

Following a process fork in Laravel, placing the following code within the child created a stable mysql client connection for me in Laravel 4.2:

```
DB::disconnect();

// we need to clone the database connection of the parent and
// create a new connection as using the original causes protocol errors

$dbconn_child = 
    [
        'driver'    => DB::connection()->getConfig('driver'),
        'host'      => DB::connection()->getConfig('host'),
        'port'      => DB::connection()->getConfig('port'),
        'database'  => DB::connection()->getConfig('database'),
        'username'  => DB::connection()->getConfig('username'),
        'password'  => DB::connection()->getConfig('password'),
        'charset'   => DB::connection()->getConfig('charset'),
        'collation' => DB::connection()->getConfig('collation'),
        'prefix'    => DB::connection()->getConfig('prefix'),
        'modes'     => DB::connection()->getConfig('modes'),
        'options'   => DB::connection()->getConfig('options'),
    ];

Config::set('database.connections.DB_CONFIG_CHILD', $dbconn_child);

DB::setDefaultConnection('DB_CONFIG_CHILD');

DB::reconnect();
```

This dynamically creates a new connection with the same parameters as the original and then switches the child process to the new connection and connects.

Simply disconnecting and reconnecting the default connection led to an assortment of mysql protocol errors similar to the OPs results.

Comment: actually, I found that if the connection parameters are exactly the same it appears PDO still connects you to the parent connection. I ended up altering the options and modes parameters in a way that didn't affect the operation in a meaningful way but was distinct to the child that prevented PDO from selecting an existing connection from the pool.